# Is the CSS asterisk a good practice

Tags: css, global-variables

I'm working on restyling an Angular app and there is a CSS rule:

```
 * {
   font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
```

and I get that this is basically applying that font to every element in the DOM.  I'm curious as to if this is a good practice, even if this is the only font we'll ever use.  I'm going to move the font into a global SASS variable and wondering if I even need to bother with the font.

Comment: Well, if you intend to use that font for everything, then why not? It's really dependent on the use case, so long as it does not include potential issues down the line then you're good to go... then again if you start adding more fonts you might have to worry about overriding, but your use is fine lol, don't worry too much.. At the end font is mostly independent of most other styles

Comment: font is a property inherited, so no need to use * for it ... it's not a good practise in this case

Comment: While I feel like this is not recommended, I suppose nowadays the performance is negligible. Maybe that's how we'll do it in a couple of years.

Answer (score 6):

Due to the cascading nature of styles it is enough to use `body { font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }`, so that every child element inherits the font-family. This does not create new instances of the definition in the selector.

Ìf you use the universal selector `* { font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }` it creates a new selector for each element.

Try the difference in your browser and check out each element with the inspector when using the universal selector.

**You should definitely go with inheritance. The universal selector will "pollute" your elements unnecessarily.**

A common use case for the universal selector is assigning an alternative box-model to every single element and pseudo element:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; // 1
}
```

Comment: Be aware that form elements will not inherit `font-family` from `body`. You must explicitly declare font-family for `button`,  `input`, `textarea`...

Comment: @enapupe They do inherit font-family from body – but get overwritten by user agent style. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Yes, I meant automatically. You could do a `font-family: inherit` for these elements.

Answer (score -2):

It's a good idea to use `*` but you don't necessarily need the `font-family` in there and the order that you place the `*` within your css matters in the example I give.

I recently saw a video or blog post (I can't remember where for the life of me) that explained that writing your css with `html { ... }` first and then letting the `* { ... }` asterisk *inherit* some of those styles gives you a slightly better performance increase.

So if you were to have a `reset.css` stylesheet, it might look something like this:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; }
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote this, you need to explain why

Comment: I did not downvote it but I suppose your answer is not precise. It has a bunch of unrelated code and it's not the best available solution. It also does not cover form elements.

Comment: I'm giving an example of how the `*` should be used, in this case with `inherit`